Github Action build-deploy Docker ASP.NET Core 8 Web API failure - Cannot find referenced projects
I am trying to build and deploy a .Net 8 Web API using a Github Action that references some other projects in the solution. I am getting the error

"Skipping project
"/src/x.Auth.Application/x.Auth.Application.csproj"
because it was not found."

Here is my Docker file:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["x.Auth.Api.csproj", "x.Auth.Api/"]
COPY ./nuget.config ./
RUN dotnet restore "./x.Auth.Api/./x.Auth.Api.csproj" --configfile nuget.config 
WORKDIR "/src/x.Auth.Api"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "./x.Auth.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./x.Auth.Api.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "x.Auth.Api.dll"]

I assume I need to also COPY the reference in the Docker file ie.
COPY ["./x.Auth.Application/x.Auth.Application.csproj", "x.Auth.Api/"]

But when the Docker file is processed, it cannot find the x.Auth.Application.csproj

ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to
calculate checksum of ref
544d66h1-12d6-4034-81g2-acacd40905b6::5c6647p590crca9mqzatprf96a:
"/x.Application/x.Auth.Application.csproj": not found

The folder structure is as follows:
x/
  x.Auth.Application/
     |__x.Auth.Application.csproj
  x.Auth.Api/
     |__x.Auth.Api.csproj
     |__DockerFile


I figured it out
I updated the context from where the Dockerfile is called from (Github Action) to point to the parent folder and x.Auth.Api/ was added to each of the paths in that Docker file
